# How enable IntellTest for "Class Library (Package)" in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellitest

In Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise command "Create IntelliTest" or "Run Intelltest" doesn't appear on the popup menu in project type "Class Library (Package)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not supported yet.
We are tracking that ask here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/9571569-enable-lntellitest-support-of-shared-projects. Please consider voting.